# Rewrite if GZIP cached file exists in split directories else send to PHP; also pass bots and non-GZIP enabled requests to PHP

Tags: nginx

I'm looking for a way to get the below rewrite "/names..." to only occur if the rewrite destination exists (is a file).

```
location ~* "^/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)" {
    if ( $http_accept_encoding ~ "gzip" )
    {
        rewrite "/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)$" /cache/html/names/$1$2/$3.html.gz last;
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

I've tried using try_files, but it is throwing a 404.

```
location ~* "^/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)" {
    try_files /cache/html/names/$1$2/$3.html.gz /data/html/names/$1$2/$3.html.gz;
    if ( $http_accept_encoding ~ "gzip" )
    {
        rewrite "/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)$" /cache/html/names/$1$2/$3.html.gz last;
        break;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    break;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Here was the code for Apache. N.B. it also has a language ISO code at the begining, e.g. /de/. But for English there is no language code.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^request=([a-z\/]*)names\/(.*?)([^/]{3})([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=LANG:%1,E=SN:%2%3/%4]
RewriteCond %{ENV:PATH}/cache/html/%{ENV:LANG}names/%{ENV:SN}.html -f
RewriteRule .* cache/html/%{ENV:LANG}names/%{ENV:SN}.html [L]
```

**COMPLETE SOLUTION**:

Here is the complete solution for my situation.

I have URLs that have an optional component for language, followed by 'name', followed by a name, e.g. 'ivanov'.

As examples:

```
/names/ivanov
/de/names/ivanov
```

These are sent to php as:

```
/index.php?request=/de/names/ivanov
```

PHP will decide based on certain criteria whether the name should be cached as a .html.gz file.

The file is cached in `/cache/html/names/`.

Owing to issues with storing [millions of files in one directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584315/placing-many-10-million-files-in-one-folder), the files are split into directories consisting of the first two characters of the name:

```
/names/ivanov => /cache/html/names/iv/anov.html.gz
```

While names of 1-2 charcters are saved like:

```
/names/ho => /cache/html/names/ho.html.gz
```

As the cache are saved as GZIP (to save ~80-90% on disk space), there is a requirement to push any requests that don't accept GZIP to PHP and not the cache.

There is also a requirement to push all requests from a defined list of IPs to PHP (not the GZIP cache). These are IPs that are used for automated scraping. When they are detected I assign them to a cgi_fastparam in nginx. This is picked up in the PHP $_SERVER variable; and I then provide random data to the automated **scraping** bot. Hence these IPs should not be allowed to view the GZIP HTML cache, which has the correct variables.

I use this method as traffic was at one point 75% bots. By blocking IPs the **scrapers** are able to tell when they are not getting the data they want. They can adjust their **scraping** or up their number of IPs. But by providing random data, you completely negate the validity of all the data they have **scraped** . This has led to a 100% reduction in **scrapers** .

The code (thanks to Ivan, below, for assistance):

Outside your nginx server configuration add:

```
map $name $gzfile {
    default $name.html.gz;
    "~^(.{2})(.+)$" $1/$2.html.gz;
}

geo $scrapers { default 0; 140.227.198.242 1; 127.0.0.1 1; }
```

The map block set vairables from the request. It defauls to the request + .html.gz; but if the request is three or more characters it splits it as iv/anov.html.gz

The geo $scrapers block is a list of IP addresses that have been identified as automated bots. By default scrapers is set to 0; but if the remote host is a defined scraper it is assigned to 1.

```
location ~* "^/([a-z\/]*)names/(.*?)([^/]+)$" {
    set $lang $1;
    set $page "names";
    set $path $2;
    set $name $3;
    if ($http_accept_encoding !~ gzip) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    if ($scrapers = 1) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    try_files /data/cache/html/$lang$page/$path$gzfile /index.php?request=$lang$page/$path$name;
    add_header  Content-Encoding  gzip;
    gzip off;
    default_type text/html;
}
```

The location block picks up URLs matching: `"^/([a-z\/]*)names/(.*?)([^/]+)$`. That is with an optional (*) language definition, e.g. 'de', 'ru'.

Variables are set from the three (parentheses) in the location regex.

The first if block checks if the request does not accept GZIP compression, and if it doesn't redirects the request to PHP. The last flag stops the further code in the block being processed.

The second block checks if the IP accessing the server is defined as a **scraper** , and if so pushed the request to PHP and does not execute further code in the block.

The try_files line checks if a GZIP HTML cache exists and loads it; else the request is pushed to PHP.

The final three lines set the content as GZIP encoded and as the HTML mime type. This tells the browser to gunzip the content and the response is HTML. Otherwise the browser will download the file or display it as Gzipped text.

```
location ~ \.php$
{
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRAPER $scrapers;
}
```

The above is also added to the server block, for handling PHP. The fastcgi_pass and include may need to be different for your system.

The fastcgi_param line adds a variable which can be accessed in PHP via $_SERVER['SCRAPER']. If it is defined in the nginx geo block listed above it will equal '1'; else '0'.

Comment: Do I understand your algorithm correctly? IF ((gzip encoding accepted) AND (.html.gz file exists)) THEN response with .html.gz file ELSE response with /index.php?request=<URI>?

Comment: Additionally, do you miss a question sign at the end of `^/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)` expression in your `location` definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand what do you need, try this:

```
location ~* "^/names/(.*?)([^/]{2})([^/]+)$" {
    set $prefix $1$2;
    set $name $3;
    if ($http_accept_encoding !~ gzip) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    try_files /cache/html/names/$prefix/$name.html.gz /index.php?request=names/$prefix$name;
}
```

Note that the last parameter of the `try_files` directive has a different meaning than all the others. As documentation [says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the *uri* specified in the last parameter is made.

Also your usage of `last` and `break` is a bit strange, there is no sense in using `break` directive after `rewrite ... last` inside the `location` block. Here is the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite). `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;` makes nginx immediately exit current `location` block and search a `location` block appropriate for `/index.php?request=...` URI.

**Update**

In accordance with the new OP's requirements, an updated solution.

Variant 1 (ugly):

```
location ~* "^/names/(.*?)([^/]{1,2})([^/]*)$" {
    set $path $1;
    set $prefix "";
    set $name $2.html.gz;
    set $suffix $3;
    set $full $1$2$3;
    if ($suffix) {
        set $prefix $2/;
        set $name $3.html.gz;
    }
    if ($http_accept_encoding !~ gzip) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
    }
    try_files /cache/html/names/$path$prefix$name /index.php?request=names/$full;
}
```

Variant 2 (using `map`):

```
map $name $gzfile {
    default $name.html.gz;
    "~^(.{2})(.+)$" $1/$2.html.gz;
}

server {
    ...
    location ~* "^/names/(.*?)([^/]+)$" {
        set $path $1;
        set $name $2;
        if ($http_accept_encoding !~ gzip) {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 last;
        }
        try_files /cache/html/names/$path$gzfile /index.php?request=names/$path$name;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works near perfectly; and much more streamlined. If there was a facility to give points here I would.

You understand correctly what I need to do. There is just one problem so far as I can see.

Requests to names longer than 2 chracters, like /names/shatsky, will are either sent to the cache if it exists or index.php if not (where the page is generated and cached).

However, if the name is 1-2 characters (/names/ho), it always goes to index.php. This isn't a huge issue as there are only 676 such pages. I will see if I can do something about it...

Comment: As far as I understand, page generated for `/names/shatsky` request will be `/cache/html/names/sh/atsky.html.gz`. What pages will be generated for `/names/sh` or `/names/s` requests?

Comment: ```/names/sh```: 1st to ```/cache/html/names/sh.html.gz``` (if file esixts); else to ```index.php?request=names/sh```. The same for ```/names/s```.

Comment: Very impressive. Works first time :D